# How do I find the entity identifier using BSYM?

Tags: data, market-data, bloomberg

I am new to BSYM and would like to do an entity-level search ([as described here (towards bottom of document)](http://bsym.bloomberg.com/sym/pages/bbgid-allocation-rules.pdf). For instance, [a search for "APPLE INC"](http://bsym.bloomberg.com/sym/) brings up 266 pages. Which one is for the entity?

I've also tried searching for BBGID "BBG001FDZ799" (the example given for Altria Group) but nothing comes up.

EDIT:
To clarify: The entity would be the issuer of the equity, debt, preferred, etc. (For cusips, the entity is the first 6 characters of the cusip identifier...just looking for something similar for BSYM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the entity level identifiers aren't part of the open symbology. The entity level identifiers are available via a data license. A so called "open" identifier list is not so open after all ;(

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing you self.

If I where to search for Apple Inc. I would:

1. look up Apple Inc. on eg. Google Finance, and find the ticker symbol (AAPL).
2. Put AAPL into the "symbol Search", click "Advanced Search Options".
3. In "Market Sector" choose "Equity".
4. In "Security Type" select "Common Stock".

That will filter out most of noise in this case.

I you want to find the different Bloomberg ID's for an instrument on a specific exchange or in a specific country/region you can ofcause, just choose something in the "Exchange" and "Country" box.

Comment: That's the stock, not the entity. An entity would be the issuer of the equity, debt, preferred, etc.